# Implement and represent polyadic operations

Tags: ocaml

I'm not sure I even know how to ask this question .. In implementing a compiler I would like to allow the client to specify, say, folds on tuples. I have provided a way to curry and uncurry a function, but only because I wrote a binary operator in Ocaml and folded it over the term and type representations. The user could not write this function.

In the macro processor, the user can write this function because tuples are lists.

For curried functions, the user can easily write transformers, because the term is binary in both the target language and the Ocaml representation of the term and the typing.

But they can't do this for tuples. Here's another example: the user easily defines serial functional composition operator. But the user cannot define parallel composition: the binary version:

```
 f1: D1 -> C1, f2: D2-> C2 --> f1 * f2: D1 * D2 -> C1 * C2
```

is easily written, but cannot be extended to 3 terms: here a fold would compute

```
 f1 * (f2 * f3)
```

instead of

```
f1 * f2 * f3
```

[isomorphic but not equal]

The generalisation of this question is "How do I implement a polyadic programming language" which is a bit too much to ask here. What I tried to do was provide a builtin transformer:

curry: T1 * T2 * T3 ... --> T1 -> T2 -> ...
   uncurry: T1 -> T2 -> .. T1 * T2 * T3

so then the user could just do folds with a binary operator:

```
uncurry (fold user_op (uncurry term))
```

but this is neither general enough nor works so well.. :)

I guess an equivalent question for Haskell would be: since Haskell has no n-ary products, the n-ary tuple constructors is simulated in the library with n functions, where each one has to be written out by hand. This clearly sucks. How would this be fixed?

[I mean, it is trivial to write a Python script to generate those n functions up to some limit n, so why is it so hard to do this in a well typed way inside the language?]

Answer (score 2):

There are two components that collaborate to cause this issue:

- Tuples are not auto-flattened - the parentheses in type expressions do more than group, they create distinct types that are joined by further tuples.  This leads to your observation that `a * (b * c)` is isomorphic but not equivalent to `a * b * c`.
- The type system does not provide a means to express algebra on tuple types.  By this I mean that the type system does not have a cons operator or any equivalent for tuples;  there is no way to express that a type has more or fewer tupled elements than another type.

The result is that there is no way to express the type of a function that operates on tuples of arbitrary length.

So, the short summary is that the OCaml type system lacks mechanisms to express the type of the function you are trying to write, and therefore you cannot write the function (setting aside nasty games with `Obj`; you could write the function, but you could not express its type to use it in a type-safe fashion).

Comment: Yes but that isn't my question: I'm not asking about what Ocaml's type system does, I'm asking how to implement this in another language (my language Felix in fact, the compiler for which is written in Ocaml).

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options.

You can make your language untyped or weakly typed. In C for example, tuples (of integers, say) can be represented as `int*`. Something would need to keep track of the tuples' lengths but the type system won't. I assume you do not want to go that way.

For a type-safe language, you need a very expressive type system. Namely, you need types that depend on values. The members of which are functions that return types. For example the tuple type constructor (not to be confused with the tuple constructor) could have type `tuple : int -> Type -> Type`.
An operation that extends a tuple could have type `forall n:int. forall T:Type. tuple n T -> T -> tuple (n+1) T`. Such type systems come at a cost: Typically, type inference is not recursive and type checking is only decidable if you are willing to annotate all kinds of subexpressions with their type (The annotations in the `forall` parts above are only a hint of what that would entail.).
This options seems to be overkill if all you want to achieve is polyadicity, though.

Disclaimer: My knowledge on type theory is a bit dated.

Comment: You're right, I do not want weak typing. However I dislike type inference so  I don't care if typing has to be explicit. Fully dependent typing would be overkill I think. Even in ATS Hongwei Xi's language), it is soon seen that when one tries to extend much beyond simple linear integer formulas the proof verification is impractical, if not intractable.

Comment: BTW: the annoying thing is that you can actually do this kind of thing fairly easily without type checking: in C++ with templates, and in Scheme. My system in Felix could actually do tuple cons, it just doesn't work with arrays (which are identical to tuples with a common element type). But one needs a lot more than just cons and uncons. With GADTs I can do more. But these collection of cool features are just hacks. Its not general. Yet I can easily do anything by just using Python to "print" the code I want.

Comment: BTW: I think there is an alternative to dependent typing (types depending on values), which is meta-typing (kinding). For example an array of length 5 in Felix is already type T^5 where the 5 is a sum of 5 units 1+1+1+1+1 where 1 is the type "unit" of value (). So IF there were a kind "Unitsum" then tuple: int -> Type -> Type would be rewritten tuple: Unitsum -> Type -> type, which no longer requires dependent typing, but instead a kinding system.